# Google Cloud Run does not load .env file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-run, python-dotenv

I spend the last couple of days trying to find what I have done wrong but I am still not able to figure out because I am able to run the app locally using `flask run` and also using Docker using `docker-compose up --build`. [Source code is here](https://github.com/Pierre-Alexandre35/messaging-service-mousset)

My issue is my Cloud Run deployment is successful but Service Unavailable when I am clicking on the [URL](https://zero-leay6xemga-ey.a.run.app/). I checked the logs and seems my environment variables are not correctly loaded:

```
line 7, in <module> from web_messaging.blueprints.user import user File 
"/web_messaging/web_messaging/blueprints/user/__init__.py", line 1, in <module> from 
web_messaging.blueprints.user.views import user File 
"/web_messaging/web_messaging/blueprints/user/views.py", line 3, in <module> from 
web_messaging.extensions import mongo, login_manager, c, bc File 
"/web_messaging/web_messaging/extensions.py", line 18, in <module> twilio_client = Client(TWILIO_SID,
TWILIO_TOKEN) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 54, in __init__
raise TwilioException("Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient") 
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioException: Credentials are required to create a TwilioClient
```

I have a `config/.env` file and a `config/settings.py`. I am loading the env variables from `.env` using  `load_dotenv()` on my `config/settings.py`. I decided to add some print and try/expect statements in my `config/settings.py` to see the value of variables.

**settings.py**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

try:
    load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '.env'))
    print("OK")
    print(BASEDIR)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

# Mongo Database
MONGO_URI = os.getenv('MONGO_URI')
TWILIO_SID = os.getenv('TWILIO_SID')
TWILIO_TOKEN = os.getenv('TWILIO_TOKEN')
print(MONGO_URI)
print(TWILIO_SID)
```

When I am running with flask run, docker-compose or on cloud-run:

- The `BASEDIR` value is `/web_messaging/config`
- There is no exceptions during the `load_dotenv()` call

However, there is one major difference, it is the value of my env variables such as `MONGO_URI`, `TWILIO_SID`. Those variables have correct values when using `flask run` and `docker-compose` but not on the Cloud Run logs. On Cloud Run, those variables are equal to `None`.

When I don't use a `.env` and directly put the value of my variables inside `/config/settings.py`, there is no issues and my Cloud Run link is working correctly. I also tried to moved `.env` outside of the config file and in few other locations but I still got the same issue.

```
.
├── requirements.txt
├── Dockerfile
├── Docker-compose.yml
├── config    
│   ├── .env                           
│   ├── settings.py            
│   ├── gunicorn.py 
│   └── __init__.py 
├── web_messaging                   
│   ├── app.py      # where I am calling create_app() - factory pattern         
│   ├── blueprints              
│   ├── static                     
│   └── ...                 
└── ...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV INSTALL_PATH /web_messaging
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --access-logfile - "web_messaging.app:create_app()"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080
        --access-logfile -
        --reload
        "web_messaging.app:create_app()"
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
    volumes:
      - '.:/web_messaging'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

**config/.env**

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=web_messaging
FLASK_SECRET=xxx
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://xxx
MONGO_DB=xxx
TWILIO_SID=xxx
TWILIO_TOKEN=xxx
```

**config/settings.py**

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASEDIR, '.env'))

DEBUG = True
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
#SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1:5000'


# Mongo Database
MONGO_DBNAME = os.getenv('MONGO_DB')
MONGO_URI = os.getenv('MONGO_URI')


# Twilio API 
FLASK_SECRET = os.getenv('FLASK_SECRET')
TWILIO_SID = os.getenv('TWILIO_SID')
TWILIO_TOKEN = os.getenv('TWILIO_TOKEN')
```

**config/gunicorn.py**

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8080'
accesslog = '-'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s" in %(D)sµs'
```

Comment: if you build and run the container locally, do you have the same issue? I'm talking about the container, not the docker-compose, perform a docker build then a docker run.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, just tried it using `docker built -t` then `docker run` and it worked. This is my source code: https://github.com/Pierre-Alexandre35/messaging-service-mousset

Comment: To be more clear I did `docker build -t helloworld .` then `docker run -p 8080:8080 -it helloworld` and it worked

Comment: It's not so easy to reproduce and to narrow the issue with your code base. In my case, I can't use dotenv with gunicorn run. I don't know why (and I'm not python expert!). But why I use dotenv on Cloud Run without gunicorn, it works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed, I found exactly what went wrong but I do not know why.

- It worked when I build my own image before to push the image on GCP container registry following those steeps:

  ```
    docker-compose up --build
    docker tag 52e6159b6b13 gcr.io/mousset005/zoro
    gcloud auth configure-docker
    docker push gcr.io/mousset005/zoro
  ```

However, what I was doing is building my Image using GCP API (which is what they recommend in the Cloud Run Python quickstart)  using that command:

```
gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/mousset005/zoro --platform managed
```

Comment: Can you please tell, how .env file is used here? How gcloud run is able to get .env file

Comment: I was going to ask the same, how/when  is the .env file even used??

Comment: Thank for your question, it was actually Flask who loaded variables from the .env: https://github.com/Pierre-Alexandre35/messaging-service-mousset/blob/develop/config/settings.py